# Nilpotency of finite ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a commutative local ring $R$ with unit. I'm curious about whether the following statements are correct:

1- every proper finite ideal is nilpotent.

2-every proper finitely generated ideal is nilpotent.

3- If maximal ideal be finite then it's nilpotetnt.

4- If maximal ideal be finitely generated then it's nilpotetnt.

Comment: Finite as in has only finitely many elements? Or finitely generated? If you can provide context where you found these questions, it would also be good to provide it for the best possible help.

Comment: So by adding these two new points, you're now asking for both versions?

Comment: @rschwieb , Finite means finitely many elements. 1 and 3 are my questions.

Comment: Any partial progress on this fountain of questions? :)

Comment: Dear Stella : Please don't jump to conclusions: I meant no disrespect. Do you want to eliminate the entire ring from being an ideal? Otherwise any finite ring is a counterexample to the first two.

Comment: An arbitrary finite ring isn't a local ring though...:-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yah of course: pencil in "local" please! Shall I try the "where I come from we assume all questions about rings in forums like this are about local rings" -style defense that's been popular lately? ;)

Comment: If $R$ be Artinian ring all  the statement are correct but $R$ isn't necessary Artinian .

Comment: Dear @rschwieb:  my comment was just a supposedly humorous repetition of your judicious comment to me... (and, by the way,  I upvoted your answer)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg That didn't escape me: I totally deserve it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $1$:

Suppose $I$ is a proper finite ideal and $|I|=n$. Take $x\in I$, $x\neq 0$ and think about $\{x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}\subseteq I$. Suppose none of these powers of $x$ in this set are zero: then  $x^k=x^m\neq 0$ for some $m> k$, but then $(x^{m-k}-1)x^k=0$, but the left hand factor must be a unit. See the end?

For $2$ look at $(x)$ in $\Bbb R[[x]]$.

For $3$ look at $1$.

For $4$ look at $2$.

---

Update: Just so there is no mistake, "the end" is not "right away." Where I left off, one should be able to conclude that $x^n=0 $ *for all $x\in I$*, and then conclude that $I$ is nilpotent by a pigeonhole-principle argument.

Comment: Excellent: +1 .

Comment: @Stella Yes: that's how I concluded $1-x^{m-k}$ is a unit.

Comment: @rschwieb , I think NAKAYAMA lemma is useful.

Comment: @Stella Yes, the Nakayama lemma is extremely useful (and would trivialize this exercise, if we weren't trying to prove it by elements :) )